# Play sound on terminal output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, terminal, linux-mint

Is there any way to play a sound when a program outputs something to a terminal?

Let's say I run:

`$ for i in {0..10}; do echo $i; done`

Can I play a sound, or run any command, on every newline printed?

More specifically, I'm running WEBrick for Rails development and I'd like to know whenever there's a request to the server without having to look at it.

(I'm using Bash on Linux Mint 17)

Comment: Does the bell character work? `echo -e "\a"`

Comment: Try this. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8607/how-can-i-play-a-sound-when-script-execution-is-ready Basically just use the `;` separator to tell BASH to execute a sound file once the first command completes.

Comment: I just get a blank line.

Comment: I can run commands sequentially, but that does not solve the problem, since the sound would only be played after the server is shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a pretty complex solution, but it does what I need.

In my .bashrc file, I added the following:

```
#ensure that the call is made only once, preventing an infinite loop

if [ $SHLVL == 1 ]
then
    script -afq ~/custom/log.txt #log everything that happens in the shell
fi

#call my script only once by checking for another instance of it

if [[ ! $(pidof -x script.sh) ]]
then
    ~/custom/script.sh&
fi
```

My script.sh file checks for changes in log.txt and plays a beep sound (you need to download it) when that happens:

```
#!/bin/bash

$(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt > ~/custom/update.txt)

while :
do
    now=$(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt)
    update=$(cat ~/custom/update.txt)
    if [ "$now" != "$update" ]
    then
        $(stat -c %y ~/custom/log.txt > ~/custom/update.txt)
        $(play -q ~/custom/beep.ogg vol 0.1) #props to franklin
    fi
done
```

This will make it so that everytime something changes in the shell, including typing, script.sh will run `play`. Now I get to know whenever there is a request to my WEBrick server without having to look at the terminal.

Answer (score 4):

You may try the AASCII "bell char" (07), by its scape char (`\a`) on `echo` command.

You must use "`echo -e`" to it parse escape chars from the input string. Example: `echo -e "line 1\nline 2"`

More info here:
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html

In BASH you can do:

```
for i in {0..10}; do echo -e "$i\a"; sleep 0.2; done
```

You can use the same scape char in Ruby *(i did test on irb)*. Try it directly on your Rails app:

```
puts "bell\a"
```

Comment: For some reason, `echo -e \n`does nothing for me. I'm using `paplay` to work around this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @fábio-queluci `echo -e \n` is translated to `echo -e n` by the shell before run the command. The `\` without quotes is used to cancel special chars. To send `\n` to a command you must put it inside a quoted string, like `echo -e '\n'` or `echo -e "\n"`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I tried `puts "bell\a"` and got nothing, just "bell". I looked it up and I think the problem is my laptop.

Answer (score 2):

You can check for a command line driven sound player like `play` from the [sox package](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

Then you can simply write the for loop so that it executes the `play` program every time there is a successful iteration of the loop.

```
for i in {0..10}; do
    # do your stuff here, presumably something like:
    `ruby /path/to/script.rb`
    echo $i
    `play /path/to/notification.ogg`
done
```

Comment: That would solve the problem for the scripts that I write, but how about the ones I don't control, like `rails s`?

Comment: Can you post here or to github the kind of rails script you're talking about? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Thanks for the `play` command tip. I needed a general solution, so there would be no need to change the script itself. A way to 'spy' the output, if you will. I'll post my solution soon. Once again, thanks for the tip, I'm using it on my solution.